# how to get the result of a SQL Server function call in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a SQL Server function that returns a number. I want to call it from Python and put that number in a variable.

```
engine = create_engine(Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
n1 = engine.execute("execute dbo.myFunction")
```

the resulting n1 is a ResultProxy object. I have not been able to figure out how to get that single number out of this object. I have tried the following that have failed:

> ```
> 1) .fetchall()
> 2) .scalar()
> 3) n1[0]
> 4) int(n1)
> 5) .fetchone()
> 6) for row in n1:
>       foo = row
> ```

I also tried to use a pyodbc cursor:

```
cursor = m.engine.raw_connection().cursor()
result1 = cursor.execute("execute dbo.myFunction")
result2 = cursor.fetchall()
```

which results in

> error: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query. 
>   Note that result1 is a pyodbc.Cursor object.

How do I get this single number out? If there is a better way to get this function to execute and get the number please share also.

Comment: If it is a scalar-valued udf, then could you instead of `EXECUTE` put it in a `SELECT` statement (disclaimer: not really a user of MS SQL Server / T-SQL)? On a glance it seems like `EXECUTE` doesn't really return values, but optionally puts the return status in a variable.

Comment: Yes, I guess I can. But that seems to be such a hack. I was hoping that there would be an elegant way to just get the returned scalar back.